# How to download a module hosted on GitHub via composer.json?

Tags: composer

I've got the following `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "contrib/term-csv-tree-import",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "type":"drupal-module",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/grahl/term_csv_tree_import.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

However after `composer update`, the module is downloaded to the `vendor` folder as:

```
./vendor/contrib/term-csv-tree-import/term_csv_tree_import.info.yml
./vendor/contrib/term-csv-tree-import/term_csv_tree_import.module
./vendor/contrib/term-csv-tree-import/term_csv_tree_import.routing.yml
```

How can I correct above configuration to download the project as a Drupal module under `docroot/modules/contrib` folder? My Drupal root is under `docroot` folder.

Comment: The module hasn't got a composer.json file so that's an impediment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need [Composer Installers](https://github.com/composer/installers) for that:

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "type": "project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "contrib/term-csv-tree-import",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "type":"drupal-module",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/grahl/term_csv_tree_import.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2"
    },   
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "docroot/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "docroot/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "docroot/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "docroot/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance of updating the codebase either on each install/update call or allowing composer to track versions for those externally hosted repos (using tags for that purpose)?

Comment: In my experience that will only work if the repo(s) in question each contain a composer.json of their own @Pjotr. So easy to do if you control the code, not so easy if not

Comment: Fortunately, we do control the codebase in our case. The repos are pretty much Drupal 8 modules, except not hosted on the official infrastructure. Could you provide a hint/link to some place that has information to either force pull on each install/update or to trick composer into updating according to tagged releases without additional changes and while still keeping that a simple GitHub repo? I did write a code that would do the pulling post install/update but would prefer not to use it.

Comment: I don't know of a way to accomplish either I'm afraid. If you want composer to update based on tags, the project needs a composer.json. I have never found a way to invoke another composer update/install at the end of an update/install, I don't think it's a workflow they've envisaged. You could hack it with bash, obviously, but I doubt it'd be pretty